# Is there a maximum size for content of an HTTP GET for both request and response?

Tags: http

Is there a maximum size for an HTTP GET? And if there is a max size, is it determined by the protocol or is it at the discretion of the server?

[Is there a maximum size for content of an HTTP POST?](https://serverfault.com/questions/151090/is-there-a-maximum-size-for-content-of-an-http-post/151092)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: Are you referring to the _request_ or the _response_?

Comment: @thebjorn that refers to url length only. The title of it should be made clearer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Response initially, but the request of the content is also welcome. I will update it to make it clear.

Comment: The response limit is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes (2 ** 64). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811824/http-content-length-and-chunked-transfer-encoding-is-there-a-2gb-limit